# Is there a simple explanation of why coupling constants run with $\log(E)$?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, interactions

The inverse coupling constants run with $\log(E)$, where $E$ is the energy or four-momentum.

Some coupling constants increase, some decrease with $\log(E)$.

Is there a simple argument that explains why the running follows $\log(E)$ and not another function of energy?

Comment: I think you  are talking of the strong interaction coupling constant used to be able to describe  with a quantum field theory the strong colored force. Weak , electromagnetic and gravity couplings are constant. Here is a review  https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08082

Comment: @annav All the couplings run. The fine-structure constant has a measured value close to 1/127 near 90 GeV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Variation_with_energy_scale (which in turn references https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0201198)

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I will read up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flippant answer to your question is that you can parameterize the energy dependence using any function you want to. If you want to know how the RG flow acts on an operator, the way to proceed is to calculate the RG flow equations for that operator and solve them. I suppose we can restate your question as, "can you give me a plausible reason, without actually solving the equations, why the RG equations should have solutions that grow like logs"? Here is at least an attempt at that version of the question.

Consider an operator in the Lagrangian with naive or engineering mass dimension $\Delta$. For example, the mass squared parameter $m^2$ in the Lagrangian has an engineering dimension $\Delta=2$, while the coefficient of a $\phi^4$ interaction (call it $\lambda$) has dimension $\Delta=0$.

The dimension of an operator $\mathcal{O}$ (or of a parameter like $\lambda$ or $m^2$) tells us how the size of that operator scales with energy
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}(E) = \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta_{\mathcal{O}}} \mathcal{O}(E_0)
\end{equation}
where $E$ is energy, $E_0$ is a reference energy scale, and $\Delta_\mathcal{O}$ is the dimension.

The net effect of the renormalization group is the modify the scaling dimension of an operator
\begin{equation}
\Delta_{\mathcal O} = \Delta^{\rm cl.}_\mathcal{O} + \hbar \Delta^{(1)}_\mathcal{O} + \cdots
\end{equation}
where $\Delta_\mathcal{O}^{\rm cl.}$ is the *classical* or *naive* or *engineering* dimension of the operator, based on dimensional analysis, and $\hbar^n \Delta_{\mathcal{O}}^{(n)}$ refers to $n$-loop corrections.

Assuming the quantum corrections are small compared the classical dimension, we can Taylor expand
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\mathcal{O}(E) }{\mathcal{O}(E_0) } &=& \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta_{\mathcal{O}}} \\
&=& \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta^{\rm cl.}_{\mathcal{O}}} \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\hbar \Delta^{(1)}_{\mathcal{O}}} \\
&=& \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta^{\rm cl.}_{\mathcal{O}}} \exp\left(\log\left(\left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\hbar \Delta^{(1)}_{\mathcal{O}}} \right)\right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta^{\rm cl.}_{\mathcal{O}}} \exp\left(\hbar \Delta^{(1)}_{\mathcal{O}} \log\left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right) \right) \\
&=& \left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^{\Delta^{\rm cl.}_{\mathcal{O}}} \left(1 + \hbar \Delta^{(1)}_{\mathcal{O}} \log\left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right) + \cdots\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore, the *corrections* to the *classical* scaling (sometimes called the naive dimension or engineering dimension) will tend to be logarithmic in energy, provided that $\Delta^{(1)}_\mathcal{O}$ is not a strong function in energy (which it is often not, in practice). This is particularly apparent if $\Delta^{\rm cl}_\mathcal{O}=0$, in other words for a (classically) dimensionless operator, since then the quantum corrections dominate the energy dependence. (Strictly speaking this sentence violates the assumption I made above that the quantum corrections are small compared to the classical dimension... well -- this answer is just a sketch, not a rigorous argument, but when you do look at beta functions it is interesting to look at the corrections to dimensionless operators).

Of course this is very sketchy and handwavy. It is only meant to convey a plausibility argument that logarithmic running is sensible. To really understand this, you should look at real examples of beta functions and try to solve the RG flow.

Comment: Beatiful - this is really insightful. Thank you.

Comment: I am still thinking about your fascinating answer. Can I ask why exactly the renormalization group changes the scaling dimension of an operator? You write that this is due to the loops. Is there a similarly simple way to see that loops have the effect of changing the operator dimension?

Comment: @Christian An example is the electron charge, or the closely related fine-structure constant alpha. Classically this is just a number that doesn't change with scale; you know that the renormalization group causes this coupling to depend on energy, which means that the dimension of alpha has changed due to quantum effects. One physical picture people give of this, is that the electron pulls electron-positron pairs out of the quantum vacuum, and these effectively screen the electron charge. As you get closer to the electron (higher energies), the screening effect decreases, and alpha increases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization#Vacuum_polarization_tensor

Comment: This is all well known. But why does the renormalization group modify the scaling dimension in precisely the way you mentioned above?

Comment: @Christian At some level of precision it stops being useful to give analogies and you need to look at some actual math :) Essentially what you are asking about is the derivation of the anamolous dimension of an operator (for dimensionless operators this is the beta function). This is derived in standard QFT texts. Here are some relevant wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_dimension, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callan%E2%80%93Symanzik_equation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group

Comment: The RG flow tells us how couplings and correlation functions change with scale. That is also what a dimension does. So in that sense, it's not surprising that the RG flow and the dimension are related.